# LINQ GroupBy over

Tags: c#, linq

This might have been dealt with, so I apologize in advance for that.

Anyway, this is my somewhat contrived example, i hope it gets my question across:

Say we have these classes

```
class WordExamples 
{
   public string word;
   public List<Sentence> sentencesWithWord;
   //constructor
   public WordExamples(string word) {
      this.word = word;
   }
}

class Sentence 
{
   public List<string> words;
}
```

Then we set up two lists:

```
List<Sentence> sentences = GetSomeSentences();
List<WordExamples> wordExamples = 
    GetSomeWords().Select(w=>new WordExamples(w));
```

As you can see the list of WordExamples contains word examples that are incomplete in that they don't have the sentencesWithWord List instantiated.

So what I need is some neat Linq that will set this up. I.e. something like: 
foreach wordExample get the subset of sentences that contain the word and assign it to sentencesWithWord. (Withouth nested for loops that is)

**edit:**
Adding public access modifier

Comment: How can any code assign to `sentencesWithWord` when it's a private field that's not used in the class that declares it?

Comment: @svick, yeah it's unproofed pseudo code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LINQ is a **query** language, not an assignment language, you *should* use a loop:

```
List<WordExamples> wordExamples = GetSomeWords().Select(w=>new WordExamples(w))
                                                .ToList();


foreach(var wordExample in wordExamples)
{
    wordExample.sentencesWithWord
        = sentences.Where(x => x.words.Contains(wordExample.word)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This code closes over the loop variable and will not work correctly.

Comment: @Ani: The code compiles and runs just fine. The output is also as expected.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, the output is not expected. All members `wordExamples` will have `sentencesWithWord` set according to the last one.

Comment: @svick: Indeed, I copied an old version here. It didn't even compile without the `ToList`. Fixed. I automatically fixed it when doing my tests and forgot to put it back here... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you're after, but I *suspect* you want:

```
foreach (var example in wordExamples)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Word {0}", example.Key);
    foreach (var sentence in example)
    {
        // I assume you've really got the full sentence here...
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", string.Join(" ", sentence.Words));
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you *really* need the `WordExamples` class, you could have:

```
public class WordExamples 
{
   public string Word { get; private set; }
   public List<Sentence> SentencesWithWord { get; private set; }

   public WordExamples(string word, List<Sentences> sentences) {
      Word = word;
      // TODO: Consider cloning instead
      SentencesWithWord = sentences;
   }
}
```

This is basically just like an element of a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx), mind you...

Anyway, with that in place you could use:

```
var wordExamples = from sentence in sentences
                   from word in sentence.Words
                   group sentence by word into g
                   select new WordExample(g.Key, g.ToList());
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I don't follow your example ... WordExamples is a class, your code seems to assume differently.

Comment: @tycomiplex: My code doesn't *use* a WordExamples class as it doesn't seem to actually add any value - and you haven't provided any way of getting at the list within it anyway. (The same is true for Sentence and its word member, of course...)

Comment: Right, like I said, it's a contrived example. I too question it's value, unfortunately it's nothing I can do away with in my real world case that this corresponds which is why I included it. Fixed the access modifier though, thanks.

Comment: @tycomiplex: You've really got public fields there? Ick. Will edit for what I'd suggest instead though.

Comment: Thank you for the Linq code, it works perfect after fixing the second line to **from word in sentence.Words**

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<WordExamples> wordExamples = GetSomeWords().Select(w=>
{
   var examples = new WordExamples(w);
   examples.sentencesWithWord = sentences.Where(s => s.words.Any(sw => sw == w)).ToList();
   return examples;
}
);
```

Don't forget to set correct access modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're re-inventing an ILookup.

```
ILookup<string, Sentence> examples = GetSentences()
  .SelectMany(sentence => sentence.words, (sentence, word) => new {sentence, word} )
  .ToLookup(x => x.word, x => x.sentence);
```

Comment: Right, the WordExamples class works like a lookup, not inventing anything though, just trying to solve a work example where the class is a complex dto